# In Visual Studio C# project do files aware the other file content without putting a using statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Say If we use two separate files called a.cs and b.cs in a C# project using VISUAL STUDIO, my question is does one file aware of the other **WITHOUT** putting a **using statement** about the other file. ie In the file a.cs can we use a class that is already defined in b.cs but not putting a **using b.cs;** statement in the beginning of the file?.When we compile altogether will the project know each file content and won't raise any error?

Comment: Hi Vanna If they are not in the same name space do we need to add other files using xxxx.cs to make it aware for a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are on the wrong track here. Files **don't** interact with each other. But the classes do. **Namespaces** are used to refer to the class that are meant to be used. You can change the file name to anything several times, it won't affect your project. Moreover you can put many classes inside the **same file name** under the **same namespace** and you won't have to use `using`.

Just consider this scenario, `Namespace` are the *area code*, and the *phone numbers* are the `classes`. Being in the **same area** already, you don't have to use the *area code* to call a different number that exists in the **same area**. But if you are dialling a number **outside your area**, you would want to use the *area code*. Basically by adding *area code*(`namespace`) infront of the number, you are applying `using` to refer to the *other number*(`class`). Hope you got the idea.

**Edit: Explaining programmatically**

Suppose this is your `Area`

```
using something;
using someotherthing;

namespace MyMainNamespace
{
   private class MyMainClass
   {
      private void blahblah { ... }
   }

   private class ClassABC
   {
      private void blahblah { ... }
   }

   private class ClassXYZ
   {
      private void blahblah { ... }
   }
}
```

See, in the above example, to interact with the `MyMainClass`, `ClassABC` & `ClassXYZ`. you don't have to use `using MyMainNamespace;`. Because they all lie in the same area `MyMainNamespace`. But there exists a `class` in another `namespace` like shown below:

```
using something;
using someotherthing;

namespace SubNamespace
{
   public class SecondaryClass
   {
      public void apple{ ... }
   }
}
```

If you want to access `SecondaryClass` which lies in `SubNamespace`(different area) you would have to use `using SubNamespace;` in your main area. Like:

```
using something;
using someotherthing;
using SubNamespace; //add the namespace

namespace MyMainNamespace
{
   private class MyMainClass
   {
      private void blahblah {
      ... 
      // Now you can use methods & functions that exist in `SecondaryClass`
      SecondaryClass secondary = new SecondaryClass();
      secondary.apple(); 
      ....
      ....
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this is enough to get the idea by now

Also, it doesn't matter that these namespace(`MyMainNamespace` & `SubNamespace`) lies in the same file or different file. You **NEVER REFER TO THE FILENAME(filename.cs)** by applying `using`. You **ALWAYS REFER TO THE NAMESPACES**.

Comment: Thanks. Do we need to add using NameoftheOtherNamespace; or using NameoftheotherClassname??

Comment: @QUser as I explained in my answer, `using` is used to refer to the `class` that exist in another `namespace`. So, as you have asked if the `class` exists in another `namespace`, you would use `NameoftheOtherNamespace`. I've modified my answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

If the C# code in a.cs and b.cs are inside the same namespace, then no using statement should be needed.  If the 2 cs files use different namespaces, then you will have to put a using statement for the namespace of the code you want to reference.

Comment: Hi Anthony if they use different name space do we need to add by using xxx.cs; or using nameoftheothernamespace;

Comment: using nameoftheothernamespace;